# Folder names start with a blank " " I need to remove the blank at the begining of all folders

Tags: powershell

I have a windows server. The file structure has thousands of directories that start with a BLANK " " and actual spacebar blank. I need to remove that blank.

Comment: My apologies, there are sub directories at least 15 levels down

Answer (score 4):

So, they start with a space?

```
# List directories where the name starts with a space
 # Rename them by replacing a space at the start with nothing
gci -Directory -Recurse -Filter " *" | ren -New {$_.Name.TrimStart()} -WhatIf
```

NB. It will throw errors if there's a folder which already has the name without a space.

Comment: `$_.TrimStart()` might be easier for the OP to work with.

Comment: You can omit the space it is not required. It trims space by default

Comment: @Matt Er, of course. Wouldn't be much use if it trimmed nothing by default, eh?

Comment: OK, so exactly what is my script. I am a newb at best. The help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @MikeKelley I've updated my answer; that would be the script - or just run on the PowerShell command line from the root folder. I've tested it quickly on subdirectories, but it's a quick one-liner, there's no guarantee - take a snapshot and a backup and stuff first, eh. Also `-WhatIf` on the end will stop it from making any changes, it will just tell you what it would do. You'd need to remove that bit to actually run it.

Comment: Here is what I have run. It does not come back with any errors!! gci -Directory |? {$_.Name.StartsWith(" ")} | ren -newname {$_.TrimStart(' ')}

Comment: I can't tell what the double exclamation mark means. Hooray, no errors? It looks right. You didn't add the flag `-Recurse` to `gci`, so it wouldn't do subdirectories. Did it do anything?

Comment: You guys are all rockstars!! Thanks so much for the help!!